# return function variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, function, variables

How to pass the variable from function ??

This is my function, I did the query and get the result successfully 
I also confirmed that `x=1` by `console.log(x)`, So I can sure that `x` is set.

```
 function checktype(x){

     (Do something)

      var x = rows[0].type;  // [ RowDataPacket { type: 2 } ]
      return x; //x=2

};
```

Here is the API part.  I use the function `checktype()` here but I cannot get the returned value. I also try to run `checktype(a);` only but I cannot get the result / x too.

```
 router.post("/check",function(req,res){
    var a = req.body.a;
    var result = checktype(a);

    console.log(result); //undefined 

 });
```

Comment: For `var x = rows[0].type; `, the `type` is real key for `rows[0]`? Also confused with `});` in the `checktype` function, some typo?

Comment: Yes , because thats mysql result . " }); " is typo

Comment: this `var x = rows[0].type;` in the callback function right?

Comment: Do you have any asynchronous calls in function checktype ?

Answer (score 1):

From your example I read that data is retrieved from a MySQL database. This is an asynchronous operation, so you have to add a callback or promise.

So when you are sure your function is running synchronous code, then you can safely use 'return x', else node will continue with the code after 'var x ='

Please note that making functions synchronous is generally bad for performance.

so for this function, add a callback:

```
function checktype(x, callback){
    mysql.query(query, function (error, rows, fields) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error,0);
        } else {
           var x = rows[0].type;  // [ RowDataPacket { type: 2 } ]
           callback(0,x);
        }
    });
};
```

And then call this function and handle the callback;

```
router.post("/check",function(req,res){
        var a = req.body.a;
        checktype(a, function(error, x){
            if (error){
                res.status(500).send({"message" : "internal server error"});
            }
             else{
            res.status(200).send(x);
            onsole.log(result); //undefined 
          }
        };
     });
```

Hope this helps! (sorry about the indentation)